# Applying ito integral to a specific example

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Using the ito integral:

$$x_t=\int_0^t b(s,x(s)) \, ds+\int_0^t \sigma (s,x(s)) \, dB(s)+x_0$$

I want to solve this:

I have $$g(s,n(s))=\log(n(s))$$

Using ito's lemma taking the derivative I get this:

$$\frac{dn(s)}{n(s)}=d\log (n(s))+\frac{\alpha ^2 dt}{2}$$

Given:
$$dn(s)=\alpha  n(s) dB(s)+r n(s) dt$$

When I substitute I get:

$$d\log (n(s))\to \text{$\alpha $}dB(s)+(r -\frac{1}{2} \alpha ^2 )dt$$

Integrating

$$\text{log}\left(\frac{N(s)}{N(0)}\right)=\text{$\alpha $}B(t)+(r -\frac{1}{2} \alpha ^2)t $$

My issue is not to understand what the log rules are doing my issue is why is log applied to $x_0$ and not to everything on the right hand side of the ito integral defined above.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see a $\log$ being applied to an $x_0$ anywhere here, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas $x_0 $ in the ito integral, In the integration it is Log(N(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the differential equation

$$dX_t = b(t) \, dt + \sigma(t) \, dB_t \tag{1}$$

is (by definition!) to be understood as an integral equation, i.e. $(1)$ is equivalent to saying that

$$X_t - X_0 = \int_0^t b(s) \, ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) \, dB_s.$$

Now in your setting, this menas that

$$d \log(n(s)) = \alpha \, dB(s) + \left(r- \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \right) \, ds$$

is equivalent to

$$\log(n(t))-\log(n(0)) = \int_0^t \alpha \, dB_s + \int_0^t \left(r- \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \right) \, ds$$

which, in turn, is obviously equivalent to

$$\log \left( \frac{n(t)}{n(0)} \right) = \alpha B_t + \left(r- \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \right) t.$$